# travis CI - how to test "my_github_repo/project"

Tags: odoo, travis-ci

In travis CI used with a python project,  I need to test the content of a subdirectory in my repo (and not the root of my github repo).

I tried to add:

```
before_install: cd project
```

but I still get in my log":

> Working in /.../user/my_github_repo
>
> WARNING! Nothing to test- exiting early.

Maybe using a variable?
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

TIA

Answer (score 0):

in case it might be useful to others:

following https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-travisyml

I used in .travis.yml file:

- TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR="/home/odoo/build/user/repo/odoo-addons"